# Why is StreamWriter writing crosses and Chinese characters?

Tags: c#, streamwriter

I have a little script that converts a pixel art image into a string, using 'X' for opaque pixels, ' ' for transparent pixels, and '\n' after each row. I want to then write this string to a text file, which seems simple enough.

```
    [SerializeField] Sprite sprite;
    [SerializeField] string newFileName;
    private string textFilesFolderLocation = //A location on my computer.
    private string fileExtension = ".txt";

    public void CreateTextDocument() {
        string ascii = CreateAscii();
        
        string path = textFilesFolderLocation + @"\" + newFileName + fileExtension;
        if (File.Exists(path)) {
            File.Delete(path);
        }

        using (StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(path)) {
            streamWriter.Write(ascii);
        }
    }
private string CreateAscii() {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        Texture2D pixels = sprite.texture;
        for (int y = pixels.height - 1; y >= 0; y--) {
            for (int x = 0; x < pixels.width; x++) {
                Color pixel = pixels.GetPixel(x, y);
                if (pixel.a > 0) {
                    stringBuilder.Append("x");
                }
                else {
                    stringBuilder.Append(" ");
                }
            }
            stringBuilder.Append('\n');
        }

        return stringBuilder.ToString();
    }
```

This works as expected with ~90% of my images, but a few are writing some seemingly bizarre characters to their text files! Variations of the following:

```
"...††††††††††††††††††††††††††††††††††††††††††††††††††
††††††††††††††††††††††††††††††††††††††††††††††††砠†
⁸††††††††砠†硸††††††††††††††††††††††††††††††砠†††††
††††砠†††††砠砠††††††††††††††††††††††††††††⁸††††††††
††††††††††††..." (the full text is around 50,000 characters long)
```

After investigating, I can confirm that CreateAscii() is working correctly. Printing the string to the console reveals that it is comprised of 'x' and ' ', as expected.

I have found that attempting to write simple messages like "Hello World" works as expected, and that writing a small piece of the ascii string also works. But with the few problematic images, trying to write the whole string results in "...†砠†硸†††...".

Even if I try to write small pieces sequentially like

```
for (int i = 0; i < ascii.Length; i++) {
            using (StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(path, append: true)) {
                streamWriter.Write(ascii[i]);
            }
        }
```

I still get exclusively "...†砠†硸†††..." in my text file.

Does anybody know what might be going on?

Comment: How are you viewing the files? What encoding does the viewer think the file uses?

Comment: How are you viewing the file? Could this simply be [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake)?

Comment: "I have found that attempting to write simple messages like "Hello World" works as expected, and that writing a small piece of the ascii string also works. But with the few problematic images, trying to write the whole string results in "...†砠†硸†††..."" Can you detect any pattern in which images are "problematic" or not? What happens if you try to produce a small image that causes the problem? What is the exact corresponding output from `CreateAscii`? Can you reproduce the problem by writing that hard-coded string?

Comment: Any chance you could upload one of those files somewhere, in its raw form? (not as copy-pasted text here)

Comment: Notepad strikes again?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bush_hid_the_facts

Comment: The file content is still "+" and " ", but the program that views the file thinks it is encoded in utf16.  Turning U+0078 and U+0020 into variations of U+7820 and U+2020.  Writing a BOM ought to help.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Ha, Notepad does indeed strike again! I opened the file with a different viewer and was successfully able to copy/paste my text.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I wasn't able to detect a pattern with the problematic files. It appears the problem was with Notepad -- opening the .txt files with another viewer enabled me to copy the correct text. Thank you for the reply.

Comment: Related: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040324-00/?p=40093 https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20070417-00/?p=27223

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the helpful replies in the comments, I learned that Notepad was having trouble displaying my files correctly. Opening the .txt files with a different viewer enabled me to see the text properly.

I still don't know what the root problem was, but this is good enough for me!